# How can James Joyce's 'word' “egourge” be seen, via Greek, as “worker for the self” or "self-employed"?

Tags: etymology, greek

In *Finnegans Wake*, James Joyce uses the 'word' *egourge* (p.g. 49-50), which syntactically yields *ego-urge*, which makes sense semantically.

[Finnwake.com](http://www.finwake.com/1024chapter3/1024finn3.htm) claims that *egourge* also derives from "egoourgos (gr) - worker for the self", but, of course, Google Translate does not seem to know of any word "egoourgos".

In what sense can “egourge” be seen, via Greek, as “worker for the self” or "self-employed"?

This relates to  [essentially the same question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/does-egourge-in-finnegans-wake-derive-from-the-greek-egoourgos-meaning-work) on our sister site [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don’t know whether it actually exists/existed or not, but as a Classical Greek word, ἐγω-ουργός _egō-ourgós_ makes perfect sense: it would be an adjective meaning ‘working for oneself’, which could then easily be nominalised to a noun meaning ‘someone who works for themselves’. Compare δημι-ουργός _dēmi-ourgós_ ‘(someone who is) working for the people, demiurge’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It doesn't need to exist as an actual Greek work, only a play on Greek grammar and words!

Comment: Related:https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/does-egourge-in-finnegans-wake-derive-from-the-greek-egoourgos-meaning-work

Comment: @user240918 That is the *unanswered* question already referenced in the OP.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is it! Thank you!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Please answer formally. I have copied and saved you answer, because I need it and comments are subject to change. If you answer, it is permanent and I can even reference you. Conversely, if you're answer is correct, you are preventing anyone else from answering.